# Where can I find a list of paint properties for mapbox-gl?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I added some geojson layers to mapbox-gl and have been scrubbing the docs in search of a list of paint properties so I can style the layers. The only thing I found on the documentation page referencing `paint` is here https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers and is very underwhelming.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers is the right place to find documentation for available paint properties.

Each layer type has an own secion, e.g. for a layer of type `fill`:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers-fill

or for a layer of type `line`:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers-line

Comment: Don't know how I missed this...must have been the styling of the font for each property.

Comment: @prime90, I too find it difficult to navigate through Mapbox docs. They should be structured in a more clear way. And it's not only the font.